# Issue with CheckBox giving value by defect [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using a Checkbox, that add items to an array when the item is checked, using this listener

If I let an item checked and I destroy the activity, I use this code to check again the box of that item without adding to array.

The array is adding and removing items perfectly, but when I go to the activity again after destroy it, if I uncheck the item, is added to the array again.

Any idea?

Edit: all the getView function

```
 override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    val view:View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.menu_list, parent,false)

    val name= view.findViewById(R.id.nameItemListaMenu) as TextView
    val checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkboxMenuItem) as CheckBox

     name.text = list.get(position).name

        for (i in 0..arrayOrder.size-1){
            if(list.get(position).id==arrayOrder.get(i).id){
                checkBox.isChecked=true
                checkBox.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()
            }
        }


    checkBox.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        if (checkBox.isPressed){
            if (checkBox.isChecked){
                order.addItemToOrder(list.get(position), arrayOrder)
            }else if (!checkBox.isChecked){
                order.removeItemOrder(list.get(position), arrayOrder)
            }
        }
    })

    return view
}
```

Comment: this problem can be easily solved in two ways: 1. in the onDestroy method,set an empty listener on the checkbox. 2 Before you set the listener on the checkbox, first put an empty listener. and then the worker

Comment: this is not working. I don't know where is the problem. All of the code posted above, is in my getView function of the adapter

Comment: Edit. Added all the getView function of my adapter

Comment: why did you decide to use the onClickListener for the checkbox? have you tried to repeat the same thing only with onCheckedChangeListener? - He does well with this work

Comment: just tried with your solution and still not working...